# In Angular how to clear browser history

Tags: angularjs, browser-history

My scenario is that, when user logs out, jump to the login page. In this case, if user clicks the back button of browser, he would go into the app again. But since session is killed, then he would have some problems to fetch data from server.

so my question is, how to clear browser history or how to disable the back button of browser so user cannot go back into the app again if he is at login page?

I have tried

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', () => {
    $location.replace();
})
```

but it does not work

Comment: Looking at this backwards. Use an httpInterceptor to redirect user when data requests fail and use routing resolves to prevent access to areas that require login

Comment: can you give sample code? thanks

Comment: Read up on authorization approaches within angular apps

Comment: Messing with history would be inappropriate. It is usually handled with 'invalid session' message or so.